# Filter files on the basis of extension using Multer in Express JS

Tags: node.js, express, multer

As question title explains, I need to filter uploaded files on the basis of file extension. So, I went through the official docs and searched this website.

**What I've Tried**

I've tried solutions I came across. Files are being successfully uploaded, but the problem is how to filter files. Currently my Router.js file looks like this.

***Router.JS***

```
var multer  = require('multer');
var storage = multer.diskStorage({ //multers disk storage settings
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './public/uploads/')
    },
    limits:{
        files: 1,
        fileSize: 1024 * 1024
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        var datetimestamp = Date.now();
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + datetimestamp + '.' + file.originalname.split('.')[file.originalname.split('.').length -1])
    },
    onFileUploadStart: function(file) {
        console.log("Inside uploads");
        if (file.mimetype == 'image/jpg' || file.mimetype == 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype == 'image/png') {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
});
var upload = multer({ //multer settings
    storage: storage
}).single('profilepic');


router.post('/profile', function(req, res){
    upload(req,res,function(err){
        if(err)
        {
            console.log(err);
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("Image was uploaded");
        }
    });
});
```

I tried echoing something in `onFileUploadStart` to check if it is going into that function or not. And it was not. Besides `onFileUploadStart`, I also tried `fileFilter` as mentioned at this [link](https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/114), but it was not helpful. Any suggestions how to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check this comment in multer issue. https://github.com/expressjs/multer/issues/114#issuecomment-231591339

Answer (score 52, accepted):

An example using `multer`:

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({ //multers disk storage settings
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './public/uploads/')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        var datetimestamp = Date.now();
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + datetimestamp + '.' + file.originalname.split('.')[file.originalname.split('.').length -1])
    }
});

var upload = multer({ //multer settings
    storage: storage,
    fileFilter: function (req, file, callback) {
        var ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
        if(ext !== '.png' && ext !== '.jpg' && ext !== '.gif' && ext !== '.jpeg') {
            return callback(new Error('Only images are allowed'))
        }
        callback(null, true)
    },
    limits:{
        fileSize: 1024 * 1024
    }
}).single('profilepic');
```

Excerpted from [Node.js - File upload](https://web.archive.org/web/20171006203439/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/node.js/4080/file-upload/14210/single-file-upload-using-multer#t=201710062034397105863). The original authors were [Iceman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6237235/iceman) and [Mikhail](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5526354/mikhail). Attribution details can be found on the [contributor page](https://web.archive.org/web/2/https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/contributors/example/14210). The source is licenced under [CC BY-SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) and may be found in the [Documentation archive](https://archive.org/details/documentation-dump.7z). Reference topic ID: 4080 and example ID: 14210.

Comment: `var ext = path.extname(file.originalname);`  can you define `path` please

Comment: @KhaledRamadan Add `var path = require('path');`

Comment: Hi Im kinda new to this package @AJ . Im trying to validate my req.body before upload, where would i pass my validation function; and if it fails, will it send the error response to the client?

Comment: @O'DaneBrissett I think the file should be validated separately. You can validate the all inputs in `req.body` first and then file validation.

Comment: more efficient way is to remove `var ext = path.extname` line and add a `RegExp` to check 
eg. `const allowedExtensions = new RegExp(/.(jpg|png|jpeg)$/gi)` and test

Comment: This is only the extension right? I mean couldnt someone just change the extension and hide something nefarious? Would checking the mime type help prevent that?

Comment: @ChristopherFranko Yes, it only validates the extension. But for better security, check mime type as well.

Comment: tyvm I wrote this

`/^image\/(png|p?jpeg|gif)$/.test(file.mimetype)`

Answer (score 1):

I'm testing this alternative now. Seems viable to me but I'm still evaluating (
with typescript):

```
import crypto from 'crypto';
import multer, { FileFilterCallback } from 'multer';
import { resolve } from 'path';

const tmpFolder = resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 'tmp');

const fileSize = 50 * 1024 * 1024;

export default {
  tmpFolder,
  fileFilter: (
    request: Express.Request,
    file: Express.Multer.File,
    callback: FileFilterCallback,
  ) => {
    const acceptedTypes = file.mimetype.split('/');

    if (acceptedTypes[0] === 'image' || acceptedTypes[0] === 'video') {
      callback(null, true);
    } else {
      callback(null, false);
      callback(new Error('Only images and videos formats allowed!'));
    }
  },
  limits: {
    fileSize,
  },
  storage: multer.diskStorage({
    destination: tmpFolder,
    filename: (request, file, callback) => {
      const fileHash = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex');
      const fileName = `${fileHash}-${file.originalname}`;

      return callback(null, fileName);
    },
  }),
};
```

Comment: This is a better answer than the accepted one: we should check for MIME type of the file, not its extension...

Answer (score 0):

Complete Implementation for multiple or single files.

Note: for single file use .single('filename') or .array('filename',1)

```
  const express = require("express");
  const app = express();
  var session = require('express-session')
  const multer = require("multer");
  const path = require("path");
  var storage = multer.diskStorage({ //multers disk storage settings
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, path.join(__dirname,"uploads"))
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        var datetimestamp = Date.now();
        cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + datetimestamp + '.' + file.originalname.split('.')[file.originalname.split('.').length -1])
    }
  });

  var upload = multer({ //multer settings
    storage: storage,
    fileFilter: function (req, file, callback) {
        var ext = path.extname(file.originalname);
        if(ext !== '.png' && ext !== '.jpg' && ext !== '.gif' && ext !== '.jpeg') {
            return callback(new Error('Only images are allowed'))
        }
        callback(null, true)
    },
    limits:{
        fileSize: 1024 * 1024
    }
  }).array('profile',2);
  app.post("/upload", upload,(req, res) => {
    res.json({
      msg:"uploaded"
    })
  });

  app.use((err,req,res,next)=>{
    console.log(err.message);
    res.status(404).json({
      msg:err.message
    })
  })
  app.listen(
    8080,
    (error) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log("error");
      }
    },
    () => {
      console.log("listening at port 8080");
    }
  );
```

Note: You can create your own custom error messages by extending Error and send custom messages and status in err,req,res,next block

Answer (score -10):

If you are used to web development, you can be validated at the front end, not passed to the back end，you can try：

```
var file = files[0];  
var imageType = /image.*/;  

if (!file.type.match(imageType)) {  
     // do something  
}
```

Comment: Note that your scripts can still be manipulated at the source file in the browser console. So never rely only on frontend validation

Comment: You should never rely on frontend validation, thats 100% true, but you should `ALSO` do frontend validation, not all users are developers that can change the source code, some of them are just stupid and validation on client side will save some traffic